# SQlite: Saving/Registering Subqueries for Repeated Use

Tags: python, sqlite

Let's say I have a store with product costs that rarely change, so I set up a *costs* table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE costs VALUES (
    itemid INTEGER
    cost DOUBLE
    date DATETIME
    FOREIGN KEY(itemid) REFERENCES items(itemid)
);
```

If I want an output of the current costs and when last updated, I could do this:

```
SELECT items.name, cost, latestdate
FROM items
LEFT NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT itemid, costs.cost, latestdate
    FROM (
        SELECT itemid, MAX(date) as latestdate
        FROM costs
        GROUP BY itemid
    )
    LEFT NATURAL JOIN costs
    WHERE date = latestdate
 );
```

Is it possible to save the subquery so that this query can be written as something like:

```
SELECT items.name, cost, latestdate
FROM items
LEFT NATURAL JOIN get_current_cost();
```

Alternatively, in a "costs-before-date" situation:

```
SELECT items.name, cost
FROM items
LEFT NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT itemid, costs.cost, latestdate
    FROM (
        SELECT itemid, MAX(date) as latestdate
        FROM costs
        GROUP BY itemid
        WHERE date < *somedate*
    )
    LEFT NATURAL JOIN costs
    WHERE date = latestdate
 );

-- Change To

SELECT items.name, cost
FROM items
LEFT NATURAL JOIN get_cost_by(*somedate*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That thing is called a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html):

```sql
CREATE VIEW current_cost AS
SELECT itemid, cost, MAX(date) AS latestdate
FROM costs
GROUP BY itemid;
```

(In SQLite, [a bare column in an aggregate query works](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg).)

However, it is not possible to use parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Figuring out the appropriate search terms is always the hardest part :-/